# How to add the class on click to one element from the block and remove the same class from other?

Tags: jquery

there is the structure of the HTML:

```
<div class="serv-cat">

   <div class="category-wrap">
      <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
   </div>

   <div class="category-wrap">
      <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
   </div>

   <div class="category-wrap">
      <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

You see each first item in the category-wrap block has the class 'active-check'. Now, if the user clicks on another item in the category-wrap block, this class should b e removed where it was and added to the element that was clicked. If I only had one block category-wrap it would not be difficult. But I have three (for example) category-wrap blocks. I tried many options yesterday using jQuery. Here is one of my attempt:

```
$(".category-wrapp").on("change", ".category-content-item", function (e) {
   let test = $(this)
   if(test.hasClass("active-check")){
    test.removeClass("active-check");
    }else{
    test.addClass("active-check");
   }

});
```

And all I can do with this code is add a class after click. This is understandable, because it works with only one element.  But how do I remove the class "active-check" from the other element? I thought that I can using .children() for this purpose. But it didn't work for me either.  Please help me to figure out with this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove target class from element siblings, Then add class to itself

```js
$(".category-content-item").on( "click" , function (e) {
   // Remove class from element siblings
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("active-check");
   
   // Add class
   $(this).addClass("active-check")
 
  });
```

```css
.active-check
{
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="serv-cat">

   <div class="category-wrap">
      <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
   </div>
<hr>
   <div class="category-wrap">
      <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
   </div>
<hr>
   <div class="category-wrap">
      <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
      <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First add class, and remove same class from other siblings elements.

```
 $(this).addClass('active-check').siblings().removeClass('active-check');
```

Example:

```js
$(".category-content-item").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('active-check').siblings().removeClass('active-check');
});
```

```css
.active-check {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="serv-cat">

  <div class="category-wrap">
    <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
    <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
    <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="category-wrap">
    <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
    <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
    <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="category-wrap">
    <div class="grid-table-row active-check category-content-item">test</div>
    <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
    <div class="grid-table-row category-content-item">test</div>
  </div>

</div>
```